# Sequelize use upsert function with custom where clause

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I use `Sequelize` to communicate with my `postgres` database. I want to use the `upsert` functionality, but with custom where clause. For example I have this model for volunteers location

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var volunteer_location = sequelize.define('volunteer_location', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        deviceId: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        latitude: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(18, 14)
        },
        longitude: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(18, 14)
        },
        city: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.STRING(90)
        },
        state: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(90)
        },
        postalCode: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(16)
        },
        country: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.STRING(70)
        }
    }, {
        instanceMethods: {
            insertOrUpdate: function (requestBody, res) {
                volunteer_location.upsert(requestBody).then(function () {
                    res.sendStatus(200);
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return volunteer_location;
};
```

In the `insertOrUpdate` method I try to use the `upsert` by giving a json like

```
location = {
    deviceId: req.body.deviceId,
    latitude: req.body.latitude,
    longitude: req.body.longitude,
    city: req.body.city,
    state: req.body.state,
    postalCode: req.body.postalCode,
    country: req.body.country,
    volunteer: req.decoded.id
};
```

where volunteer is a `foreign key` from table `users`.
Now the executing says:

> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.sequelize_upsert() RETURNS integer
>   AS $func$ BEGIN INSERT INTO "volunteer_locations" *some values* RETURN
>   1; EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN UPDATE "volunteer_locations"
>   SET *some values* **WHERE (("id" IS NULL AND "volunteer" = 1))**;
>   RETURN 2; END; $func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; SELECT * FROM
>   pg_temp.sequelize_upsert();

`id` and `volunteer` is a set of primary keys. I want to change the `WHERE` clause on the `UPDATE` by checking only the `volunteer` value, because I don't know the value of the `id`.

Is this possible? Or I have to use

```
findOne(...).then(function () {
      //update
});
```

**EDIT**

I set `volunteer` with the attribute `unique: true` and it replaced the where clause with `WHERE (("id" IS NULL AND "volunteer" = 1) OR "volunteer" = 1);`, which means that the update works. But I don't know if this is very efficient. If anyone knows a better solution please let me know.